# Can we get the twitter bot to tweet to #mathematica?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

The [@stackmma](http://twitter.com/stackmma) twitter bot tweets certain questions (algorithmically determined) and converts the first tag (sorted by number of questions) to a [hash tag](https://support.twitter.com/articles/49309-what-are-hashtags-symbols). Hash tags are twitter's way of sorting things and the article says:

> - People use the hashtag symbol # before a relevant keyword or phrase (no spaces) in their Tweet to categorize those Tweets and help them
>     show more easily in Twitter Search.
> - Clicking on a hashtagged word in any message shows you all other Tweets marked with that keyword
> - Hashtagged words that become very popular are often Trending Topics

Now consider [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9788/5) that [was tweeted](http://twitter.com/StackMma/status/238833275089584129) to an obscure hashtag [#customnotation](http://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/%23customnotation)... In reality, nobody tweets/looks at such obscure #tags. In other words, our classification scheme is not a good fit for what twitter users use. In comparison, the [#mathematica](http://twitter.com/#!/search/?q=%23Mathematica&src=hash) tag shows more activity, and I believe, could become moderately trending tags during the release of version 9 or the conference (unless some celebrity has a wardrobe malfunction yet again).

Now we can't use [mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica) on our questions to enforce this as it is a blacklisted tag on this site (because it makes no sense to tag something [mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica) on a site called mathematica.SE), but I propose that the twitter bot ignore any site tag and instead tweet all questions to #mathematica. This would possibly reach a more relevant audience and possibly attract more followers.

Comment: Since the early days of the site, I run a twitter robot (MathematicaAtSE) which publishes the site's RSS feed. I've added the #mathematica tag to its output now.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries In that case, I think I'll remove this request. It's probably not wise to have two bots tweeting the same thing to the channel, which might be considered spamming

Comment: Not sure, I'd prefer the official bot to do this. I can't be sure of the services that the intermediating site provides to get this RSS->Twitter scheme running. I can always remove the hash tag if the official stackbot is set up this way.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries [meta-tag:status-completed] now!

Comment: OK, I just stopped the twitbot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All questions on Mathematica.SE that are tweeted now have the #mathematica hashtag - and *only* the #mathematica hashtag.

Comment: Thanks, Shog :)